# jQuery - Run function on each <li> of Unslider

Tags: jquery, css, unslider

I'm using [Unslider](http://idiot.github.io/unslider/) and the slider is working just fine.
I have in each `<li>` an `<h1>` as a title for the slide.
I have a  **`resizeH1()`** function to resize this `<h1>`:

```
    function resizeH1() {
    var $h1 = $('.entry-header h1');
    if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {

        // Calculate the total height of the element
        var totalHeight = ($h1.height());

        var numOfLines = totalHeight / 88;
        // Force this element height to always be 88px
        $h1.height(88);
        // Adjust $h1 font-size depending on it's number of lines
        if (numOfLines === 2) {
            $h1.css('font-size', '42px');
        } else if (numOfLines === 3) {
            $h1.css('font-size', '40px');
        } else if (numOfLines === 4) {
            $h1.css('font-size', '38px');
        } else if (numOfLines >= 5) {
            $h1.css('font-size', '28px');
        }
        // Align the $h1 text verticaly at the very end
        if (numOfLines >= 2) {
            $h1.css({
                'text-align': 'center',
                'display': 'flex',
                'justify-content': 'center',
                'align-items': 'flex-end'
            });
        }
    } else {
        // Reset the $h1 state when (window.innerWidth < 768)
        $h1.css({
            'height': '',
            'font-size': '',
            'text-align': '',
            'display': '',
            'justify-content': '',
            'align-items': ''
        });
    }
}
```

My issue is that this function is only applied to the first `<h1>` of the first `<li>` only,
and the others `<h1>` of the others `<li>` are getting the same `font-size` as the first one!

How to run `resizeH1()` on each `<li>` and not the first one only?
I've already tried everything I know and searched a lot before posting.
Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestion/help.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing your html structure. I would be awesome if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop structure. For jQuery elements you may use .each(). Your code would look like this:

```
function resizeH1() {
    $('.entry-header h1').each(function () {
        $h1 = $(this);
        if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
            // Calculate the total height of the element
            var totalHeight = ($h1.height());

            var numOfLines = totalHeight / 88;
            // Force this element height to always be 88px
            $h1.height(88);

            (...)
        }
    });
```

For more info, see [api.jquery.com/each/](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @kautella. I feel stupid :( I was doing the inverse, targeting `.each()` `.entry-header h1` then calling `resizeH1()` instead of directly looping the function itself...